# pass function over character vector with variable names

Tags: r

I would like to pass a function over a character vector or a list with variable names. I think the problem is that R does not recognize variable names in this case. I have a simple example, but I plan to do it with big data frames.

Example data:

```
> DF
   A  B  C
1 11 22 88
2 11 22 47
3  2 30 21
4  3 30 21

> v
[1] "DF,A,B"   "DF,A,C"   "DF,B,C"   "DF,A,B,C"
```

I have the function by Romain Francois:
[Loop within string in r to output expressions with vectorized values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305349/loop-within-string-in-r-to-output-expressions-with-vectorized-values)

```
library(purrr)
library(glue)
library(rlang)
tests <- function(data, ...){
names <- map_chr(quos(...), f_name)

map( names, ~{
   glue( "{name} == {values}", name = ., values = data[[.]] )
 }) %>% 
  reduce(paste, sep = " & " )

}
```

Finally, I want to pass the function over each v element, so that I do this and I get a wrong output:

```
> output=sapply(v,tests)
> output
$`DF,A,B`
NULL

$`DF,A,C`
NULL

$`DF,B,C`
NULL

$`DF,A,B,C`
NULL
```

The output would be:

```
c(
  tests( DF, A, B), 
  tests( DF, A, C), 
  tests( DF, B, C), 
  tests( DF, A, B, C)
)
#>  [1] "A == 11 & B == 22"           "A == 11 & B == 22"          
#>  [3] "A == 2 & B == 30"            "A == 3 & B == 30"           
#>  [5] "A == 11 & C == 88"           "A == 11 & C == 47"          
#>  [7] "A == 2 & C == 21"            "A == 3 & C == 21"           
#>  [9] "B == 22 & C == 88"           "B == 22 & C == 47"          
#> [11] "B == 30 & C == 21"           "B == 30 & C == 21"          
#> [13] "A == 11 & B == 22 & C == 88" "A == 11 & B == 22 & C == 47"
#> [15] "A == 2 & B == 30 & C == 21"  "A == 3 & B == 30 & C == 21"
```

It would be great if someone could help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'v' is a string.  It needs to be split up.  Here is one option using `base R`

```
tests <- function(data, ...){
  colN <- c(...)
   tmp <- get(data, envir = parent.frame())[colN]
     Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep=" & "),
        Map(paste, names(tmp), tmp, MoreArgs = list(sep=" == ")))
  
}

r1 <- c(sapply(strsplit(v, ","), function(x) tests(x[1], x[-1])))
r1
#[1] "A == 11 & B == 22"           "A == 11 & B == 22"           "A == 2 & B == 30"            "A == 3 & B == 30"           
#[5] "A == 11 & C == 88"           "A == 11 & C == 47"           "A == 2 & C == 21"            "A == 3 & C == 21"           
#[9] "B == 22 & C == 88"           "B == 22 & C == 47"           "B == 30 & C == 21"           "B == 30 & C == 21"          
#[13] "A == 11 & B == 22 & C == 88" "A == 11 & B == 22 & C == 47" "A == 2 & B == 30 & C == 21"  "A == 3 & B == 30 & C == 21"
```

---

Similarly, we can change the function in the OP's post.  Using `quos` is not needed here as our input column names are strings from the `strsplit` and this can be directly used in the `glue`

```
tests <- function(data, ...){
 names <- c(...)
 #object name i.e. data is a string
 #so using get to return the value of the object
 tmp <- get(data, envir = parent.frame()) 

 map(names, ~{
   glue( "{name} == {values}", name = ., values = tmp[[.]] )}) %>% 

      reduce(paste, sep = " & " )

 }

r2 <- c(sapply(strsplit(v, ","), function(x) tests(x[1], x[-1])))
identical(r1, r2)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
v <- c("DF,A,B", "DF,A,C", "DF,B,C", "DF,A,B,C")

DF <- structure(list(A = c(11L, 11L, 2L, 3L), B = c(22L, 22L, 30L, 
30L), C = c(88L, 47L, 21L, 21L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"),
 class =   "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```